# Access /dev/ttyACM0 from kernel

Tags: serial-port, kernel, driver, tty

I am working with a serial device on /dev/ttyACM0 in 3.0 kernel.
My task is to read and write data chunks from kernel driver. 
I can access the ttyACM0 from user-space, but the task is to read/write from my kernel module.

Comment: What specifically is giving you issues? Have you tried building your kernel module (not much different from a normal program, just how you build it and what you reference), if so what issues are you seeing that is preventing you from opening said device?

Comment: Yes i have tried to access it in normal way, but the problem is when i access, the device is not yet initialized. It's a USB dongle, that i need to send commands and get answers. I am too new to linux and kernel, that's the problem. But i have read so many help and documents, and i cannot find any tip that would help to answer my questions.

Comment: I have managed to wrap with some logic to open the device when it is ready, but i cannot neither read or write the tty device from kernel. sys_write and sys_read return -11, aka try again or no data to read but there is data.