# How to write to `/dev/ttyUSB?` in kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, tty

i want to send and receive data from/to an arduino connected to a /dev/ttyUSB port (serial) from a kernel module. i have seen enough ways how to do it in userspace, but that's not my question.

it would really help to be able to access a tty by major and minor numbers (188, 0 for /dev/ttyUSB0) as i dont want to use file io in a kernel module

related but didnt answer my question:

[How to write to a tty from kernel space with only major and minor device numbers available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230506/how-to-write-to-a-tty-from-kernel-space-with-only-major-and-minor-device-numbers) (1 answer but uses userspace)

[Access /dev/ttyACM0 from kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786717/access-dev-ttyacm0-from-kernel) (no answers yet)

[How can I write to TTY from a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719713/how-can-i-write-to-tty-from-a-kernel-module) (1 answer but how to get the `struct tty_struct` from a serial port?)

[Read and write to Arduino serial using a kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173557/read-and-write-to-arduino-serial-using-a-kernel-module) (1 answer but uses file io and alternative is too vague)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585573/how-does-serial-driver-get-attached-to-a-tty-port (no answers yet)

Comment: You need to use in-kernel APIs, otherwise why not to do it in user space?

Comment: "i have seen enough ways how to do it in userspace, but that's not my question."

Comment: i want to do it 100% in kernel space

Comment: Write a driver and bind it to a corresponding serdev. If there is no serdev, try to find if ACM has any in-kernel APIs, if not, you need to develop them. Opening a file, esp. for a hotpluggable device is an utterly wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SappyInsane on linuxquestions had the same problem and gave me his solution which worked
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/reading-from-arduino-serial-in-a-kernel-module-4175704822/